# tox does not find numpy

Tags: python, numpy, tox

I try to run tox in order to automatically test my project. My tox file is very simple:

```
[tox]
envlist = py3

[testenv]
deps = pytest
commands =
    pytest --doctest-modules
```

I also have a requirements.txt file that defines the required modules:

```
cmake
osqp
numpy
cvxpy
networkx
matplotlib
```

and a setup.py file:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
... 
requirements = ["numpy","cvxpy","networkx","matplotlib"]
... 
setup(
    name='fairpy', 
    version='1.0', 
    description=...,
    packages=find_packages(),
    install_requires=requirements, 
    ...
)
```

But when I run tox from the terminal, I get an error saying that the module numpy is not found:

```
GLOB sdist-make: /mnt/d/Dropbox/ariel/fairpy/setup.py
py3 inst-nodeps: /mnt/d/Dropbox/ariel/fairpy/.tox/.tmp/package/1/fairpy-1.0.zip
py3 installed: attrs==19.3.0,fairpy==1.0,more-itertools==8.1.0,packaging==20.1,pluggy==0.13.1,py==1.8.1,pyparsing==2.4.6,pytest==5.3.4,six==1.14.0,wcwidth==0.1.8
py3 run-test-pre: PYTHONHASHSEED='188600482'
py3 run-test: commands[0] | pytest --doctest-modules
========================================================== test session starts ==========================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.8.1, pytest-5.3.4, py-1.8.1, pluggy-0.13.1
cachedir: .tox/py3/.pytest_cache
rootdir: /mnt/d/Dropbox/ariel/fairpy
collected 0 items / 20 errors                                                                                                           

================================================================ ERRORS =================================================================
__________________________________________________ ERROR collecting Deng_Qi_Saberi.py ___________________________________________________
Deng_Qi_Saberi.py:13: in <module>
    from agents import *
agents.py:10: in <module>
    import numpy as np
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
...
```

I have numpy installed - in my python 3.8.1 terminal, I can import numpy with no problem.

What am I doing wrong with tox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First,

> I have numpy installed - in my python 3.8.1 terminal, I can import numpy with no problem.

tox creates a virtual environment when you run it so it doesn't matter if you have numpy installed on your computer original interpreter.

Second,
If you want tox to install the requirements file you must add 
`deps = -rrequirements.txt` to tox.ini.
And you can always add numpy manually as a dependency there as well.
Third,
tox has some dependencies tracking issues in some cases. Try run tox -r to force tox to recreate its environment and make sure that numpy mentioned in the "install_requires" section in the setup.py.